# Unable to read object properties in IE8

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I have the following code, and it does not work in IE8 (works perfect in Firefox):

```
response = eval('({"success":true,"statuses":[{"title":"Unknown","code":"UNKNOWN","cssClass":"sys_unknown","id":1}]})');

for (var i in response.statuses) {
    status = response.statuses[i];
     if (status.id != undefined) {
        alert('ID = ' + status.id);
     }
}
```

Can someone tell what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You also should not iterate arrays with `for/in`.  You should use the general form: `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
response = eval('({"success":true,"statuses":[{"title":"Unknown","code":"UNKNOWN","cssClass":"sys_unknown","id":1}]})');

var s = response.statuses;
for (var i=0,len = s.length;i<len;i++) {
    var st = s[i];
     if (typeof st.id != 'undefined') {
        alert('ID = ' + st.id);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`status` is a reserved keyword in IE. Try to rename your var.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to always declare your variables with the `var` keyword. If you don't, they will become properties of the `window` object, effectively adding them to the global scope.

The reason why it doesn't work is because of this line: `status = response.statuses[i];`

You don't need to rename your variable because you're not in global scope, as long as you declare it with the var keyword:
`var status = response.statuses[i];`